# Foreach() with if statements not affecting variables

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to add an InventoryState to the various products extended from my IProduct interface I created before, but the foreach() statement I made to check the state of the inventory is not changing the default value of Unassigned on the property...

This is the properties for each product object:

```cs
    public string ProductType
        {
            get { return "Apple"; }
            set { }
        }

        public double BulkPrice
        {
            get { return 0.99; }
            set { }
        }

        public double RetailPrice
        {
            get { return 1.49; }
            set { }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return 50; }
            set { }
        }

        public int MaxQuantity
        {
            get { return 100; }
            set { }
        }

        public InventoryState Status
        {
            get { return InventoryState.Unassigned; }
            set { }
        }
```

And these are the various declarations and the foreach in question:

```cs
public enum InventoryState
    {
        Full,
        Selling,
        Stocking,
        Empty,
        Unassigned
    }

public interface IProduct
{
    string ProductType { get; set; }
    double BulkPrice { get; set; }
    double RetailPrice { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    int MaxQuantity { get; set; }
    InventoryState Status { get; set; }
}

public static IProduct[] ProductList =
{
    new Apple(),
    new Blueberry()
};
```

```cs
foreach (IProduct productName in ProductList) // broken- not being called :(?
            {
                if (productName.Quantity == productName.MaxQuantity)
                {
                    productName.Status = InventoryState.Full;
                    return productName.Status;
                }

                else if (productName.Quantity <= (productName.MaxQuantity * (0.5)))
                {
                    productName.Status = InventoryState.Stocking;
                }

                else if (productName.Quantity == 0)
                {
                    productName.Status = InventoryState.Empty;
                }

                else
                {
                    productName.Status = InventoryState.Selling;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're setters are all empty (they don't set a backing field) and the getter of  `Status` is hard-coded to always return `InventoryState.Unassigned;` Why do you expect a different result?

Comment: @RenéVogt However that doesn´t explain why the loop shouldn´t iterate.

Comment: You should use your debugger and step through your code to determine the actual values for your properties.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just read the question again, can't find a error description stating that the loop doesn't run, only that it doesn't change the properties.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, why do you think you loop doesn't iterate?

Comment: `/ broken- not being called :(?` that maybe?

Comment: `public string ProductType { get; set; } = "Apple"; public double BulkPrice {get; set;} = 0.99; ...`

Comment: @HimBromBeere, The problem statement: `is not changing the default value of Unassigned on the property`

Comment: @HimBromBeere, once again, did you trace it? You sure it doesn't call? Or he is asking calls it or not

Comment: @NoImagination Why should I? When OP writes "is not called" I rely on that information. I won´t make **guesses** on what OP *may* have written.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, because he wrote **not called** with sign **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always do in your automatic properties

```
get { return "some value";}
```

Even if you assign a value to it, it will always return "some value" even if the underlying value is different.

Do this for **all** your properties:

```
 public string ProductType
        {
            get; set;
        } = "Apple";
```

They will have default value "Apple" but it will get assigned and returned correctly.

Note that auto property default value is only from C# 6.0 onward.

Otherwise you need a private backing field.